# Expressjs Firebase React Redux Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I've been researching this issue for several hours now and found something odd. Using ExpressJS, Firebase, and React for a small app, and need to call the Firebase Database via the Express Backend, and I also need to make post requests to store data in the database via the Express Backend.

***Functionality***: I make a post request to the backend to add data to the database. Since Firebase is real time db, the data will immediately reflect on the page.

***Problem***: The issue is, when I make a post call to the backend and that completes, the page refreshes but the data doesn't show because of this 
ERROR: **[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

```
/**
 * Add new note to Firebase
* Real-Time Database
*/
app.post('/addNote', (req, res)=> {
var title = req.body.note.title;
var body  = req.body.note.body;
var userId= req.body.note.uid;

db.notes.push({
    title: title,
    body: body,
    uid: userId
})
res.send("Success")
})

app.get('/all', (req, res, next)=> {
 db.notes.on('value', snapshot => {
       return res.send(snapshot.val());
})
})
```

***Possible Solution***: I've found that using the code below, I can make a post request, **manually** refresh the page, and the data will reflect with no header error. I'm trying to code the proper functionality but can't seem to figure out where the code is sending multiple responses with the db.notes.on because I'm only sending res.send one time. The clear difference is (.on listens and updates immediately, while .once requires manual refresh)

```
/**
 * Add new note to Firebase
* Real-Time Database
*/
app.post('/addNote', (req, res)=> {
var title = req.body.note.title;
var body  = req.body.note.body;
var userId= req.body.note.uid;

db.notes.push({
    title: title,
    body: body,
    uid: userId
})
res.send("Success")
})

app.get('/all', (req, res, next)=> {
 db.notes.once('value', snapshot => {
       return res.send(snapshot.val());
})
})
```

Comment: I wrote a quick answer below to explain the difference between `on` and `once`, and why `on` may be sending multiple responses. If you still have a problem using `once` please edit your question to explain what exactly that problem is.

Answer (score 0):

An `on("value"` listener to Firebase will fire:

1. straight away with the current value of the data,
2. and will then later also fire when the data changes.

Since you're sending the data in the response to the client in #1, the response will be closed/finished by the time #2 happens.

By using a `once("value"` listener this problem doesn't happen, since `once()` removes the listener after #1.

Comment: Hey Frank, I appreciate your response. I've spent more time trying to write the code in a way that allows for me to use the .on("value" listener but since it's sending multiple responses, I can't seem to find how to stop at least one response so that it doesn't error out. Is this the only way to write a .on("value", or can I make a change here? app.get('/all', (req, res, next)=> {
     db.notes.on('value', snapshot => {
           return res.send(snapshot.val());
    })
})

Comment: Why do you need to use `on()`? What does it do that you need, which isn't also done by `once()`?